# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator inserting from dual

Tags: sql, oracle

```
INSERT INTO DIM_TEMPS (ID_DATE, DATE_DU_JOUR, ANNEE_CALENDAIRE,
  SEMESTRE, LIBELLE_SEMESTRE, TRIMESTRE, LIBELLE_TRIMESTRE,
  ANNEE_MOIS,MOIS, LIBELLE_MOIS, SEMAINE, JOUR, LIBELLE_JOUR,
  JOUR_FERIE, JOUR_OUVRE, QUANTIEME_JOUR)
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "YYYYMMDD")) AS ID_CALENDRIER,
  DT_CAL AS DATE_DU_JOUR,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "YYYY")) AS ANNEE_CALENDAIRE,
  ROUND(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "Q"))/2) AS SEMESTRE,
  CASE ROUND(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "Q"))/2)
    WHEN 1 THEN "1er semestre"
    ELSE "2ème semestre" END AS LIBELLE_SEMESTRE,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "Q")) AS TRIMESTRE,
  CASE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "Q"))
    WHEN 1 THEN "1er trimestre"
    ELSE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "Q")) || "ème trimestre"
    END AS LIBELLE_TRIMESTRE,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "YYYY"))
    || LPAD(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "MM"), 2, "0")) AS ANNEE_MOIS,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "MM")) AS MOIS,
  TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "Month") AS LIBELLE_MOIS,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "IW")) AS SEMAINE,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "DD")) AS JOUR,
  TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "Day") AS LIBELLE_JOUR,
  CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "D") IN ("6", "7")
    THEN "Oui" ELSE "Non" END AS JOUR_FERIE,
  CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, "D") IN ("6", "7")
    THEN "Non" ELSE "Oui" END AS JOUR_OUVRE,
  NUM_JOUR AS QUANTIEME_JOUR
FROM (
  SELECT to_date("19000101","YYYYMMDD") + (rownum - 1) AS DT_CAL,
    rownum AS NUM_JOUR
  FROM dual connect BY to_date("19000101","YYYYMMDD") + (rownum - 1)
);
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Why are you using double-quotes for (most) string literals?

Comment: because when i add 1 quote and i run it pot un error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using double-quotes around (most of) your string literals. Often that leads to 'invalid identifier' errors, but here they are confusing the parser even more that.

Just change them all to single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO DIM_TEMPS (ID_DATE, DATE_DU_JOUR, ANNEE_CALENDAIRE,
  SEMESTRE, LIBELLE_SEMESTRE, TRIMESTRE, LIBELLE_TRIMESTRE,
  ANNEE_MOIS,MOIS, LIBELLE_MOIS, SEMAINE, JOUR, LIBELLE_JOUR,
  JOUR_FERIE, JOUR_OUVRE, QUANTIEME_JOUR)
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'YYYYMMDD')) AS ID_CALENDRIER,
  DT_CAL AS DATE_DU_JOUR,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'YYYY')) AS ANNEE_CALENDAIRE,
  ROUND(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'Q'))/2) AS SEMESTRE,
  CASE ROUND(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'Q'))/2)
    WHEN 1 THEN '1er semestre'
    ELSE '2ème semestre' END AS LIBELLE_SEMESTRE,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'Q')) AS TRIMESTRE,
  CASE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'Q'))
    WHEN 1 THEN '1er trimestre'
    ELSE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'Q')) || 'ème trimestre'
    END AS LIBELLE_TRIMESTRE,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'YYYY'))
    || LPAD(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'MM'), 2, '0')) AS ANNEE_MOIS,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'MM')) AS MOIS,
  TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'Month') AS LIBELLE_MOIS,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'IW')) AS SEMAINE,
  TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'DD')) AS JOUR,
  TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'Day') AS LIBELLE_JOUR,
  CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'D') IN ('6', '7')
    THEN 'Oui' ELSE 'Non' END AS JOUR_FERIE,
  CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DT_CAL, 'D') IN ('6', '7')
    THEN 'Non' ELSE 'Oui' END AS JOUR_OUVRE,
  NUM_JOUR AS QUANTIEME_JOUR
FROM (
  SELECT to_date('19000101','YYYYMMDD') + (rownum - 1) AS DT_CAL,
    rownum AS NUM_JOUR
  FROM dual connect BY to_date('19000101','YYYYMMDD') + (rownum - 1)
    <= to_date('29991231','YYYYMMDD')
);
```

You could simplify this in various places but it will now generate the data, and insert (lots of) rows.

Comment: please i have another bug which is ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("BMT"."DIM_PORT"."ID_DIM_PORT") when i write this request  

insert into DIM_PORT (NOM_PORT) select distinct pdisc from ARR_BAYPLAN; please i need a help .thank you

Comment: please i have another bug which is ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ('BMT'.'DIM_PORT'.'ID_DIM_PORT') when i write this request  

insert into DIM_PORT (NOM_PORT) select distinct pdisc from ARR_BAYPLAN; please i need a help .thank you

Comment: Well, your ID_DIM_PORT column is defined as not-null, so you have to supply a value for that when you insert. Maybe you have a sequence to populate that from. A trigger is often used to automate that. If that isn't clear (or even obvious) then ask a new question. It will have been asked many times before though.

Comment: yes i have created a sequence auto increment but my id is not null.look that : CREATE TABLE  DIM_PORT 
   ( ID_DIM_PORT NUMBER(3,0), 
 NOM_PORT VARCHAR2(10), 
  PRIMARY KEY (ID_DIM_PORT) 
   ) ;

Comment: Really, ask a new question. See [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Include the sequence definition and trigger in that.

Comment: please explain for me : i insert my id is 1

Comment: please explain for me

Comment: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into

Comment: hi, i have this error 
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis: